# Conection between components React - shopping-cart

Tags: reactjs, components, shopping-cart

I tried to bulid shopping cart in React I don't use redux so I think it can be a problem too. I have now alomost done application so I want to finish it in this way without using redux. Ok whats the problem. I made function to add items into the shopping cart in component counter but I don't want to display this products in this component but in main component App in header. In component counter I creat component ShoppingCart to display the products - but I want to only push products into the ShoppingCart but display them in component App.

I tried a lot of diffrent methods but it's not working. I can display products but really not in the place I want. I think the problem is how I can comunicate with my items between components.

This is my Counter

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Counter";
import "./Counter.css";
import ShoppingCart from "./ShoppingCart";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    availableProducts: 20,
    shoppingCart: 0,
    cart: []
  };

  handleRemoveFromCart = () => {
    this.setState({
      shoppingCart: this.state.shoppingCart - 1
    });
  };

  handleAddToCart = () => {
    this.setState({
      shoppingCart: this.state.shoppingCart + 1
    });
  };

  handleAddProductsToCart = props => {
    // console.log("clicked", this.props.name, this.state.shoppingCart)
    let found = false;
    const updateCart = this.state.cart.map(cartItem => {
      if (cartItem.name === this.props.name) {
        found = true;
        cartItem.productsNumber = this.state.shoppingCart;
        return cartItem;
      } else {
        return cartItem;
      }
    });
    if (!found) {
      updateCart.push({
        name: this.props.name,
        productsNumber: this.state.shoppingCart,
        key: this.props.name
      });
    }
    this.setState({
      cart: updateCart
    });
    // return <ShoppingCart cart={updateCart} />;
    // console.log(updateCart);
  };

  render() {
   const cart = this.state.cart.map(cartItem => (
     <ShoppingCart
        name={cartItem.name}
        productsNumber={cartItem.productsNumber}
        key={cartItem.key}
      />
    ));
    return (
      <>
        <div className="counter">
          <button
            className="buttonCount"
            disabled={this.state.shoppingCart === 0 ? true : false}
            onClick={this.handleRemoveFromCart}
          >-</button>
          <span> {this.state.shoppingCart} </span>
          <button
            className="buttonCount"
            disabled={
              this.state.shoppingCart === this.state.availableProducts
                ? true
                : false
            }
            onClick={this.handleAddToCart}
          >
            +
          </button>
          <button
            className="buy"
            disabled={this.state.shoppingCart <= 0 ? true : false}
            onClick={this.handleAddProductsToCart}
          >Add to cart</button>
        </div>
        <div>{cart}</div>

      </>
    );
  }
}
```

export default Counter;

and this is Shopping

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import "./ShoppingCart";
import "./ShoppingCart.css";

class ShoppingCart extends Component {

  render() {

      return (
        <>
        <div>{this.props.name}</div>
        <div>{this.props.productsNumber}</div>
        </>
      );
    }
  }


export default ShoppingCart;
```

If you have any suggestions it will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code can help you

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Counter";
import "./Counter.css";
import ShoppingCart from "./ShoppingCart";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    availableProducts: 20,
    shoppingCart: 0,
    cart: []
  };

  handleRemoveFromCart = () => {
    this.setState({
      shoppingCart: this.state.shoppingCart - 1
    });
  };

  handleAddToCart = () => {
    this.setState({
      shoppingCart: this.state.shoppingCart + 1
    });
  };

  handleAddProductsToCart = props => {
    // console.log("clicked", this.props.name, this.state.shoppingCart)
    let found = false;
    const updateCart = this.state.cart.map(cartItem => {
      if (cartItem.name === this.props.name) {
        found = true;
        cartItem.productsNumber = this.state.shoppingCart;
        return cartItem;
      } else {
        return cartItem;
      }
    });
    if (!found) {
      updateCart.push({
        name: this.props.name,
        productsNumber: this.state.shoppingCart,
        key: this.props.name
      });
    }
    this.setState({
      cart: updateCart
    });
    // return <ShoppingCart cart={updateCart} />;
    // console.log(updateCart);
  };
CreateCard=(cartItem)=>{
console.log(cartItem)
     return(
          <ShoppingCart
             name={cartItem.name}
             productsNumber={cartItem.productsNumber}
             key={cartItem.key}
           />
     );
     }
  render() {
  
    return (
      <>
        <div className="counter">
          <button
            className="buttonCount"
            disabled={this.state.shoppingCart === 0 ? true : false}
            onClick={this.handleRemoveFromCart}
          >-</button>
          <span> {this.state.shoppingCart} </span>
          <button
            className="buttonCount"
            disabled={
              this.state.shoppingCart === this.state.availableProducts
                ? true
                : false
            }
            onClick={this.handleAddToCart}
          >
            +
          </button>
          <button
            className="buy"
            disabled={this.state.shoppingCart <= 0 ? true : false}
            onClick={this.handleAddProductsToCart}
          >Add to cart</button>
        </div>
        <div>{this.state.cart!=null?this.state.cart.map(cartItem => (this.CreateCard(cartItem))):""}</div>

      </>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I hope help you

Comment: Thank you I will try your sugestion :) Thank you very much.

Comment: I changed the code but it's still the same. The products display under the button Add to cart. Thank you :)I really don't know whats the solution. I thought that maybe display it like popUp but then it dosen't work like shopping list.